# Secure purchase premium IAP

Tags: android, kotlin, in-app-purchase

I have an app that i want to use google pay for only 1 non-consumable upgrade , I use below code to get status of my google play purchase

```
override fun onPurchasesUpdated(
    billingResult: BillingResult?,
    purchases: MutableList<Purchase>?
) {
    if (billingResult?.responseCode == BillingClient.BillingResponseCode.OK && purchases != null) {
        for (purchase in purchases) { 
            handlePurchase(purchase) 
            // set user preference bool value if status is purchased 
        }
    } 
}
```

and set the bool preference to true to hide ads , from google here

https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_library_overview

In section `Verify a purchase` They say

> Note: It's highly recommended to verify purchase details using a secure backend server that you trust. When a server isn’t an option, you can perform less-secure validation within your app.

my question is

**Is that a usual practice or i should use a server to verify from reverse engineering and if so Wouldn't that happen also with the server ?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is that a usual practice or I should use a server to verify from reverse engineering?

It is a good practice, but it is not a usual practice.

What I mean is not everybody can afford a private server. Sometimes you have an offline app, and you offer in-app purchases just to unlock a few other features and you don't want to get into the hassle of having a private server just for the sake of it. It depends:

Is your app is extremely popular with thousands of DAU?

Are you unlocking some really useful features, that if 1% of users are using a modded version of your app, it will really justify the server costs? Most of the time it does not.

> and if so Wouldn't that happen also with the server?

Yes, it can, the server is just another layer of security.

I would suggest hiding your public key using NDK which is harder to reverse engineer and you should be quite safe.

You can find the tutorial [here](https://blog.mindorks.com/securing-api-keys-using-android-ndk)